# Undefined refrence to function in codeblocks?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>

void LoginMenu(char *usr[30],char *pass[30]);
void portal(char *usr[30],char *pass[30]);
void SalesDepartement( );
main(){
    char usr[30]={0},pass[30]={0};
    int ans=0;
    LoginMenu(&usr,&pass);
    portal(&usr,&pass);
}

void LoginMenu(char *usr[30],char *pass[30]) {

    printf("\t\t\t\t\t\tLogin Menu\n\n");
    printf("Username:");
    scanf("%s",&*usr);
    printf("Password:");
    scanf("%s",&*pass);
    //printf("%s\t %s",usr,pass);
}

void portal(char *usr[30],char *pass[30]){
    int ans=0,nt;
    if(strcmp(usr,"SalesAdmins")==0 && strcmp(pass,"Sales2020")==0){

        system("cls");
        printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tDepartement Name : Sales Departement");
        printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tAccount Status : limited access !");
        printf("\nAvailable Functions:");
        printf("\n\n1-customer account mangament\n\n2-go to sales\n\n3-Log Out\n\nyour answer (in numbers):");
        scanf ("%d",&ans);


        if(ans==1){
            //CustomerID();
        }
        else if (ans==2){
            SalesDepartement();
        }
        else if (ans==3){
            system("cls");
            main();
        }
        else if(ans>3 || ans<1){
            printf("\a\nPlease Enter A Valid Choice!\n\n");
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            portal(&*usr,&*pass);
        }
    }
    else if(strcmp(usr,"FinancialAdmins")==0 && strcmp(pass,"Financial2020")==0){
        system("cls");
        printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tDepartement Name : Financial Departement");
        printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tAccount Status : limited access !");
        printf("\nAvailable Functions:");
        printf("\n\n1-Create A Financial Report\n\n2-View Analytics\n\n3-Log Out\n\nyour answer (in numbers):");
        scanf ("%d",&ans);


        if(ans==1){
            //CustomerID();
        }
        else if (ans==2){
            //SalesDepartemet();
        }

        else if (ans==3){
            system("cls");
            main();

        }

        else if(ans>3 || ans<1){
            printf("\a\nPlease Enter A Valid Choice!\n\n");
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            portal(&*usr,&*pass);
        }

    }


    else if(strcmp(usr,"InventoryAdmins")==0 && strcmp(pass,"Iventory2020")==0){
        system("cls");
        printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tDepartement Name : Inventory Departement");
        printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tAccount Status : limited access !");
        printf("\nAvailable Functions:");
        printf("\n\n1-Go to Inventory\n\n2-Log Out\n\nyour answer (in numbers):");
        scanf ("%d",&ans);


        if(ans==1){
            //CustomerID();
        }

        else if (ans==2){
            system("cls");
            main();

        }

        else if(ans>2 || ans<1){
            printf("\a\nPlease Enter A Valid Choice!\n\n");
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            portal(&*usr,&*pass);
        }
        //  InventoryDepartement();

    }

    else if(strcmp(usr,"HrAdmins")==0 && strcmp(pass,"Hr2020")==0){
        system("cls");
        printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tDepartement Name : Hr Departement");
        printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tAccount Status : limited access !");
        printf("\nAvailable Functions:");
        printf("\n\n1-Go to Hr Management\n\n2-Log Out\n\nyour answer (in numbers):");
        scanf ("%d",&ans);


        if(ans==1){
            //CustomerID();
        }

        else if (ans==2){
            system("cls");
            main();

        }

        else if(ans>2 || ans<1){
            printf("\a\nPlease Enter A Valid Choice!\n\n");
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            portal(&*usr,&*pass);
        }
        //  HRDepartement()

    }

    else if(strcmp(usr,"CEO")==0 && strcmp(pass,"19104381")==0){
        system("cls");\
            printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tDepartement Name : Head Departement");
        printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tAccount Status : Full Access !");
        printf("\nAvailable Functions:");
        printf("\n\n1-customer account mangament\n\n2-go to sales\n\n3-Create A Financial Report\n\n4-View Analytics\n\n5-Go to Inventory\n\n6-Go to Hr Management\n\n7-Log Out\n\nyour answer (in numbers):");
        scanf ("%d",&ans);


        if(ans==1){
            //CustomerID();
        }

        else if (ans==2){


        }

        else if (ans==3){


        }

        else if (ans==4){


        }

        else if (ans==5){


        }

        else if (ans==6){

        }

        else if (ans==7){
            system("cls");
            main();

        }


        else if(ans>2 || ans<1){
            printf("\a\nPlease Enter A Valid Choice!\n\n");
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            portal(&*usr,&*pass);
        }
        //  SalesDepartemet();

    }
}

void SalesDepartemet()  {
    //first
    system("cls");
    double tax=0.14;
    struct Sales{

        int custid;
        int employid;
        char method[30];
        int paid;
        int total;
        int recieve;
    }sale;

    printf("Enter Customer ID:");
    scanf("%d",&sale.custid);
    printf("Enter Employee ID:");
    scanf("%d",&sale.employid);
    printf("Enter Payment Method:");
    scanf("%s",&sale.method);
    //fisrt

}
```

the compiler shows me undefined reference to the function SalesDepartement(); when I try to call it from the portal function from an if statement, I don't know what is this silly error I almost tried everything and did not work , why is it showing me that in the first place when my function is defined above , is this a problem with the compiler? or have I messed up the code

Comment: Where is your definition of `SalesDepartement()`? I've done a text search of this page and found only a declaration and an invocation.

Comment: I've never heard of `<strings.h>`. And why is your indentation absolutely all over the place? Present a [mcve] in a neat form, please, and tag only the actual language you're asking about.

Comment: Also please do not tag `C++` as this is clearly pure `C` code

Comment: What do you expect when you write `&*usr`? You mix pointer and array for your strings

Comment: randomly adding `&` and `*` until it compiles, isn't a good way to program

Comment: @CoryKramer the site rules are that the question should be tagged according to which compiler is in use.  Writing C++ in the style of C is still C++ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You left the 'n' out of `SalesDepartement` in your definition of the function.

Comment: oh thanks very much, I never thought the error would be as small as correcting the function definition name

Comment: how so, I'm new to the platform

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 0):

regarding;

```
char usr[30]={0},pass[30]={0}; 
.... 
portal(&usr,&pass);
```

in C, a 'bare' reference to the name of an array degrades to the address of the first byte of the array, so the call to `portal()` should be:

```
portal( usr, pass );
```

then the signature:

```
void portal(char *usr[30],char *pass[30]);
```

is claiming that the parameters are pointers to arrays of pointers. This should be:

```
void portal( char *usr, char *pass );
--OR-- 
void portal( char usr[ 30 ], char pass[ 30 ] );
```

the problem of passed parameters, that the compiler passes as a pointer (not an array of pointers) is found in several places in the posted code.

regarding:

```
main(){
```

this is not a valid signature for `main()` and will cause the compiler to output a warning message:

```
untitled1.c:8:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int].
```

A valid signature would be:

```
int main( void )
```

regarding the prototype:

```
void SalesDepartement( );
```

When prototyping a function signature that will not receive parameters, always insert `void` between the parens. Other wise the compiler produces code that can take any number of parameters of any type. Suggest:

```
void SalesDepartement( void );
```

OT: for ease of readability and understanding (the compiler does not care)

1. follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*
2. insert a 'reasonable' space: inside parens, after commas, after
   semicolons, inside brackets, inside braces, around C operators.
3. insert a blank line around code blocks: `for` `if` `else` `while`
   `do...while` `switch` `case` `default`.
4. insert 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent) between functions.

regarding:

```
system("cls");
```

this is not portable ( for instance linux does not recognize `cls` as a valid shell command

regarding:

```
 printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tDepartement Name : Sales Departement");
 printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tAccount Status : limited access !");
 printf("\nAvailable Functions:");
 printf("\n\n1-customer account mangament\n\n2-go to sales\n\n3-Log Out\n\nyour answer (in numbers):");
```

it is always best to 'honor' the right margin.  (not all terminals have 'infinite' width for lines and lines will be chopped off when printing.  Suggest: (including a few spelling corrections)

```
printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tDepartement Name : Sales Department"
       "\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tAccount Status : limited access !"
       "\nAvailable Functions:\n\n"
       "1-customer account management\n\n"
       "2-go to sales\n\n"
       "3-Log Out\n\n"
       "your answer (in numbers):");
```

regarding;

```
scanf ("%d",&ans);
```

The user can do lots of things to make this call to `scanf()` fail, like entering a EOF or entering a letter.  Always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  and what happens if the user enters a number outside the range 1...3 or only a return?  Suggest:

```
while( 1 )
{
    if( scanf( "%d", &ans ) == 1 )
    {
        // insert the switch() statement (from later in this answer) here
    }

    else
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "scanf failed to input the menu selection\n" );
        int ch;
        while( ( ch = getchar() ) != EOF && ch != '\n' );
    }
}
```

regarding:

```
    if(ans==1){
        //CustomerID();
    }
    else if (ans==2){
        SalesDepartement();
    }
    else if (ans==3){
        system("cls");
        main();
    }
    else if(ans>3 || ans<1){
        printf("\a\nPlease Enter A Valid Choice!\n\n");
        system("pause");
        system("cls");
        portal(&*usr,&*pass);
    }
```

This recursive call to `portal()` is a very poor idea as it never 'unwinds' the stack.

This sequence of `if()` statements results in the target variable `ans` being repeatedly tested.  Much better to only test it once.  Suggest:

```
    switch(ans)
    {
        case 1:
            //CustomerID();
            break;

        case 2:
            SalesDepartement();
            break;

        case 3:
            exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );
            break;
      
        default:
            printf( "%d is invalid, try again\n", ans );
            break;
    }
```

regarding:

```
system("cls");
main();
```

NEVER call the function: `main()` from your code.  If you want to 'start over' then implement a loop in the `main()` function

Similar considerations exist for the code blocks starting with:

```
 else if(strcmp(usr,"InventoryAdmins")==0 && strcmp(pass,"Iventory2020")==0){
```

and

```
else if(strcmp(usr,"CEO")==0 && strcmp(pass,"19104381")==0){
```

in the above code, the spelling: `SalesDepartement();` does not match the actual function, those spelling is: `SalesDepartemet()`

regarding:

```
printf( "Username:" );
scanf( "%s", usr );
```

There is nothing stopping the user from entering a string that is over 29 characters long.  The result would be a buffer overflow and undefined behavior.  The 'input format conversion' specifier should have a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer because the `%s` specifier always appends a NUL byte to the input. and always check for failure: Suggest:

```
printf( "Username:" );
if( scanf( "%29s", usr ) != 1 )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "scanf for user failed\n" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
```